# Is it possible to calculate urban electric power Hz frequency

Tags: c#, asp.net, registry, bios

I have no idea if it is possible to calculate urban electric power Hz frequency, on PC without any external electric or electronic device.
I want to get electric power Hz through Os, power supply, motherboard or any other data source available in a normal PC, best practical code for me is C#.
Usually, in many countries, electric current is 50 or 60 Hz. Now I want to calculate it in my code, on my computer, without any external device, and best case is that code be so harmless to run on remote server, internet server without need for any special permission. In CMOS, BIOS and windows registry there are many hidden data, may be one usefull for this.
Any help is welcomed.

> **EDIT** No, don't miss understand, I don't need to know countries current Hz, I want to know Hz of power that my Pc is using, Here
>   (local place) power Hz and at the present time

Comment: Why not just keep a dictionary of country -> Hz and find out which country they are in?

Comment: @dav_i In Japan it wouldn't work :-) There are two frequencies, 50 and 60hz

Comment: No, don't miss understand, I don't need to know countries current Hz, I want to know Hz of power that my Pc is using, Here (local place) power Hz and at the present time.

Comment: hmmmm interesting, I think the PC works of DC from the powersupply so it prob dosnt know what the powersupply input is. However, if it has a microphone you may be able to detect the background noise?

Comment: As I remeber some motherbords had things like fan speed and so on, So I hope there would be something for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks promising:

http://wutils.com/wmi/root/cimv2/power/ms_409/win32_powersupply/

This is WMI, and should be doable through C# assuming it actually works and gives you what you need

http://wutils.com/wmi/root/cimv2/power/ms_409/properties/range1inputfrequencyhigh.html

```
Dim wmiObject
Set wmiObject = GetObject( _
 "WINMGMTS:\\.\ROOT\CIMV2\power\ms_409:" + _
 "Win32_PowerSupply.CreationClassName=""Value"",DeviceID=""Value"",SystemCreationClassName=""Value"",SystemName=""Value""")
Wscript.Echo wmiObject.Range1InputFrequencyHigh
```

Comment: have you got this code working? I'm getting errors from the c# code that site supplies

Comment: seems to work for batteries and stuff https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389273(v=vs.85).aspx#_hmm_power_classes

Comment: did not get a chance to test this out. this looked like the most promising lead.

Comment: also that code seems to be vbs, so for C# code there might be more work. What kind of errors are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you may be able to use the sound card and microphone to detect the mains power supply frequency

see the section on System frequency-response analysis

http://www.techmind.org/audio/

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a very special equipment, the power supply doesn't tell anything to the Motherboard (and so to the OS). It's perhaps possible to query the Motherboard about the DC current it receives, but it would be useless for what you are trying to do.

As always, if no one has done it before you, there are two possibilities: you are a genius or it can't be done. Normally sadly it is the second one :-)

Comment: bit of a defeatist attitude! option 3: new inventions have made it possible recently

Comment: @Ewan Here there is the pinout of an ATX PSU: http://pinouts.ru/Power/atx_v2_pinout.shtml . There is no communication bus. And I don't know of "standard" PSU with a USB cable. Now, while your idea is very interesting, I do think he recognized that the peak was caused by the frequency of the current because he knew the frequency of the current. Hadn't he known the frequency of the current I'm not sure he would have been able to measure it (and it worked because his speaker was connected to AC... had it been a self-alimented USB speaker or a laptop speaker it wouldn't have worked)

Comment: its a round about technique to be sure, but most electronics will pick up the mains power background noise, its just a matter of listening for it where you can get at the raw data, obviously there are only a limited number of frequencies you have to check